# Getting the current location exactly once when my android application opens

Tags: android, gps, location

I can see many examples of getting location. But in almost all the cases we have a listener to listen location changes. But what I need is the current location exactly once when the application opens in the device and no more location update should happen again unless the application gets restarted. Can any body provide some clue? I am new to android programming, hence might be asking a silly question, but i really need to know how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Location location = context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE).getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

Location: fast, cheep and, inaccurate.
Beware it can return null.

Consider using the listeners if you want anything other then the general neighborhood of the device.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. As you say it might be highly inaccurate and may be null sometimes, is there a way where I will use listener, but it will stop listening once it gets an accurate location. May be I can break the question into two. 1. can I measure the accuracy of a location? 2. If 1 is possible, is it possible to stop listening once I get the accurate fix (May be I have to unregister the listener)

Comment: @Sush: Yes there is, the way you just described.

Comment: @Sush Yes you can: [getAccuracy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy%28%29)